# Capturing groups of movie title

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to capture the following groups from a movie title:

```
file = "The Great Home Se01E01 Meatballs for Dinner"

<show> = "The Great Home"
<season> = "Se01"
<episode> = "E01"
<title> = "Meatballs for Dinner"
```

For the time being, I only partially managed to capture  and  using the following code:

```
import re

file = "The Great Home Se01E01 Meatballs for Dinner"
seasonEpID = re.search(r'(\bS/?.+\d{1,2})+(E/?.+\d{1,2})', file)
print(seasonEpID.groups())
```

Which returns the following:

```
('Se01', 'E01')
```

How can one capture the four groups `<show>`, `<season>`, `<episode>`, `<title>`?

Comment: [Just add two more groups in the start and end?](https://regex101.com/r/PiCaTO/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
file = "The Great Home Se01E0k1 Meatballs for Dinner"
match = re.fullmatch(r"(?P<show>.+?) (?P<season>Se\d+)(?P<episode>E\d+) (?P<title>.+)", file)
print(match.groupdict() if match else "No match") 

'''
{
  'episode': 'E01',
  'season': 'Se01',
  'show': 'The Great Home',
  'title': 'Meatballs for Dinner'
}
'''
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```regex
^(.*?)\s+(Se\d+)(E\d+)\s+(.*)$
```

Sample script:

```py
file = "The Great Home Se01E01 Meatballs for Dinner"
parts = re.findall(r'^(.*?)\s+(Se\d+)(E\d+)\s+(.*)$', file)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
[('The Great Home', 'Se01', 'E01', 'Meatballs for Dinner')]
```